# Pagination in createNativeQuery

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I want to implement Pageable in my custom query.Below is the code I am using.The sql is dummy query.Could someone please tell me how can I  calculate total rows,lastelement from following?

```
EntityManager em = OpenJPAUtils.openEntityManager();
String sql="select DISTINCT student.studentId from student where ... LIMIT  :limit OFFSET  :offSet ; "  
query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("limit", pageable.getPageSize());
query.setParameter("offSet", pageable.getPageNumber());
query.getResultList()
```

I want total counts but the limit I have used will only give that much only. I could use the same query without limit to count the total rows but the query is very big and I don't want to run the same query twice to get total counts and calculate the rows.
I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: So you need total rows of result, and in last result what you want to calculate?

Comment: @SachinGupta I want total counts but the limit I have used will only give that much only. I could use the same query without limit to count the total rows but the query is very big and I don't want to run the same query twice to get  total counts and calculate the rows.

Comment: Use a count query to get the total number of rows.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use pagination provided by JPA?

```
query.setFirstResult(firstIndex);
query.setMaxResults(firstIndex + pageSize);
```

Then no need for `LIMIT` clause in sql:

```
String sql="select DISTINCT student.studentId from student where ..."
```

Comment: This does same job, internally it appends limit and offset.